# ASP.NET MVC and REST URI's

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest

How would I handle something like the below uri using ASP.NET MVC's routing capability:

```
http://localhost/users/{username}/bookmarks/ - GET
http://localhost/users/{username}/bookmark/{bookmarkid} - PUT
```

Which lists the bookmarks for the user in {username}.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first you need to create a new route in global.aspx

```
routes.MapRoute("Bookmarks", "{controller}/{user}/{action}/{id}");
```

then add a new action

```
public class UsersController : Controller
{
    [AcceptVerbs("Post")]
    public void Bookmarks(string user, int? id)
    {

        //add your bookmark
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [AcceptVerbs] attribute on your action method

```
public class BookmarksController : Controller
{
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public void Bookmarks(string user)
    {

        //add your bookmark
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public void Bookmarks(string user, int? id)
    {

        //add your bookmark
    }
}
```